# W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10120 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android

My Android app is throwing this error:

```
D/tag: https://www.example.net/stagingarea/Toronto/products/json_confirm/7731/1/3/
W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:612>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10120 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2005)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1951)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getDeviceId(ITelephony.java:5506)
W/System.err:     at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId(TelephonyManager.java:1100)
W/System.err:     at com.paypal.android.c.k.a(Unknown Source:97)
W/System.err:     at com.paypal.android.c.f.B(Unknown Source:4)
W/System.err:     at com.paypal.android.c.f.d(Unknown Source:0)
W/System.err:     at com.paypal.android.c.f$3.run(Unknown Source:675)
I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=502KB, data=399KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=496KB, data=334KB
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=503KB, data=335KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=503KB, data=335KB
I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 2MB
I/Choreographer: Skipped 79 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10120 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2005)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1951)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getDeviceId(ITelephony.java:5506)
W/System.err:     at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId(TelephonyManager.java:1100)
W/System.err:     at com.paypal.android.c.k.a(Unknown Source:97)
W/System.err:     at com.paypal.android.c.f.B(Unknown Source:4)
W/System.err:     at com.paypal.android.c.f.d(Unknown Source:0)
W/System.err:     at com.paypal.android.c.f$3.run(Unknown Source:675)
```

I tried to solve it by using this code:

```
int permissionCheckREAD_PHONE_STATE = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        if(permissionCheckREAD_PHONE_STATE != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }
```

However, with this new code I am getting this error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE'
```

I am already using `import android.Manifest;`, which I thought would already include what is needed for `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`. In my `AndroidManifest.xml`, I have included this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Any ideas about why I am getting this `Cannot resolve symbol 'REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE'` error?

UPDATE 1: The exact error that I am getting is:

```
Error:(164, 96) error: cannot find symbol variable REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE` was a constant that I needed to define. I fixed it by defining it and adding the corresponding code that I needed using that constant:

```
public static final int REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 8;
```